# How to invoke an Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the result of an `Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))`, but I'm not sure how Expressions work.

Here's where I am with my experiments

```
<Extension>
Public Function Test(Of T, TResult)(site As Object, expr As Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))) As Boolean

    Dim result As Object = Nothing
    result = Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile.DynamicInvoke
    result = result()

End Function
```

Here's the code I'm using to set up the test.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim dummy As Object = New Object
    Dim result As Boolean = dummy.Test(Function(x As A) x.Bee.Tag)

End Sub

Public Class A

    Public Property Bee As B = Nothing

End Class


Public Class B

    Public Property Tag As Object = Nothing

End Class
```

Note this code is simply for exploration and learning.  It is definitely in no way shape or form production-ready.

The error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: No default member found for type 'Func(Of
>   A,Object)'.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should stop and turn `OPTION STRICT ON`.

Really. Everytime. Just turn `OPTION STRICT ON`. Always (except if you really know what you're doing and you really need late binding).

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to do. Also, you can't write extension methods for `Object`.

Nonetheless, if you want something working out of your code, have a look at this:

```
Sub Main
    ' create an object which we'll use in Test '
    Dim obj = New A With { .Bee = New B With { .Tag = "Hello" }}

    ' call the Test function with an expression '
    Dim result = Test(obj, Function(x As A) x.Bee.Tag)

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Class A
    Public Property Bee As B = Nothing
End Class

Public Class B
    Public Property Tag As Object = Nothing
End Class

Public Function Test(Of T, TResult)(obj As T, expr As Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))) As Boolean

    ' compiling the expression yields a function that creates a Func(Of T, TResult) '
    ' So let's create a Func(Of T, TResult) from the expression '
    Dim result = DirectCast(Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile().DynamicInvoke(), Func(Of T, TResult))

    ' the Func(Of T, TResult) takes a T, so call it with obj '
    Return result(obj).Equals("Hello")

End Function
```

This example is still somewhat lame as you could simply use a `Func(Of T, TResult)` in `Test`, but it shows how to compile the `Expression` to create a `Func(Of T, TResult)` which can be used later on.

Also, turn `OPTION STRICT ON`.